# BitmapRegionDecoder native code

Tags: android, open-source

Does anyone know where exactly the Android native source code lies, specifically related to `BitmapRegionDecoder`?  I'm doing some native work with large images and I'm interested to see how exactly they're storing the image to see if I can leverage it on the native side.  I've checked android.googlesource.com, but I wasn't able to find the jni stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As usual 5 more minutes of searching revealed the answer:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni

and particularly:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.cpp